# make dir upload images it show error in next uploading image

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I have created a php file first makes dir to upload image second part uploads image to it, but next time it again try to make dir and give error, script should accept created dir and continue to upload images:also check  is it the script ok or suggest better script to upload images and display images.

```
<?php
//create the new directory
$newDir = mkdir('newupload', 0777);

$info_file_exts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$info_upload_exts = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($info_upload_exts, $info_file_exts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
    $info_file_exts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    if($info_file_exts[0]=='jpg'){
    $ink=explode('.'.$info_file_exts[0],$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $time=time();
    $info_new_file_name =$ink[0].'_'.$time.'.'.$info_file_exts[0];
    }
    else if($info_file_exts[1]=='jpeg'){
    $ink=explode('.'.$info_file_exts[1],$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $time=time();
$info_new_file_name =$ink[0].'_'.$time.'.'.$info_file_exts[0];
    }
    else if($info_file_exts[2]=='gif'){
    $ink=explode('.'.$info_file_exts[2],$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $time=time();
    $info_new_file_name =$ink[0].'_'.$time.'.'.$info_file_exts[0];
    }
    else if($info_file_exts[3]=='png'){
    $ink=explode('.'.$info_file_exts[3],$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $time=time();
    $info_new_file_name =$ink[0].'_'.$time.'.'.$info_file_exts[0];
    }

    $info_old_file_path="newupload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $info_new_file_path="newupload/" . $info_new_file_name;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "newupload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    // echo "<div class='sucess'>"."Stored in: " . "c:\wamp\www\upload/newupload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]."</div>";
    $name=rename($info_old_file_path,$info_new_file_path);
    echo "<img src='newupload/" . $info_new_file_name."' style='width:300; height:250px;' />";
    echo "</br>Your file is ".$_FILES['file']['name']."  uploaded.";
    }
    }

    else
    {
    echo "<div class='error'>Invalid file</div>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: use if(!is_dir('file path')){ mkdir('newupload', 0777); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace line

```
if (!file_exists('newupload')) {
     $newDir = mkdir('newupload', 0777);
}
```

It will check if file/folder exist it will not try to create it again.

Comment: thanks for  solving problem   now again opening page should show all pictures but it shows only uploaded image will u plz help me

Comment: Can you please see me where you had written file read code? I think if it displaying only uploaded images then it may be permission issue to the file which are already there.

Answer (score 0):

Check that directory is set or not, after than create directory like below,

```
if(!is_dir($newDir))
{
  //create the new directory
  $newDir = mkdir('newupload', 0777);
}
```